# Listening for Expo push notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

I'm really confused on how notification listener works in expo, especially for a killed app, I read the doc and I knew that *addNotificationResponseReceivedListener* listener use when the app is ( in background or killed). I need to know how this listener work and when I unsubscribe the listener does it keep listening?

Answer (score 0):

this callback is called after the user taps on the notification and the App open. you will receive an object with the push notification info (like title, message and extra data) and from there you can decide if you will redirect the user somewhere or just resume the app flow.

If the app is not subscribed (if you didn't generate the token for push notification) you will not receive the notifications.

If you just didn't create the callback `responseListener.current = Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(response => {.....` your app will show the notifications anyway (normally you just use the callback when you want to do some action with the notification info)

Hope this info helps.